# statistics question on confidence intervals pigs

Tags: statistics

[image]
Help, i really don't understand any part of this question.It is on confidence interval but i dunno what to actually do, for the whole 50 marks.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Do a t-test of difference between sample means.

(b) This is better because the pigs were littermates, so control over other variables is better.

(c)95% confidence interval is the other dimension of a significance test. At what level are you willing to reject the null of no difference in diets.

Hope this helps.